# Twilio Voice: Tracking a user from website to twilio phone call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I'm trying to see if this is even possible in twilio.  I'm hoping maybe someone's had a similar challenge and came up with a creative solution...

Our company has a unique phone number that's only displayed on our website.  I've been asked if it's possible to find out not only how many calls we're getting (which is simple enough to track in twilio), but also who's calling.  Basically, they want to follow the details of a users activity.  From website to phone call.

Theoretically, they'd like something like this:

1. A user, lets call him John, comes to the website & is assigned a unique id of "12345".  The id is stored in a cookie for returning users (this I can already handle).
2. If John calls the phone number displayed on the website, we...somehow through the use of twilio...know it's user #12345.
3. We can then create monthly reports stating user #12345 called the phone number 7 times this month for a total of 18 minutes.

There's so many "what if's" that go into this, that I'm just not sure it's even possible, but perhaps someone knows of a creative way this can work?  A few things I've considered, but none of them are foolproof:

1. Tracking a combination of John's geographical location while browsing the website and the time of web browsing, then using twilio voice to track the geographical location & time of the phone call, to make a best guess.  The problem is it sounds like twilio voice isn't always great at providing geo location.
2. Tracking mobile click to calls on the website, then matching the time of the click to the time of the phone call.  Several problems with this, including multiple users calling at the same time, and we'd only be tracking those who browsed the website via mobile, then clicked to call.
3. For mobile click to call, passing the user's id via a phone extension, which twilio then reads (not sure if this is even possible in twilio).  But again, this would be limited to mobile users.

So, I'm just not sure if this is even possible.  Any idea's on how this could be implemented?

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Have you considered making it possible to make the calls through the website itself? If you implemented [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/client) you would be able to directly track users who called from the website and they'd be able to do so without picking up the phone too. That direct connection would allow you to make the calls more personal too, as you'd know exactly which user was calling.

Check out the tutorial on [implementing browser calls in Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/browser-calls/php/laravel) and let me know what you think.

I can't think of any straightforward ways to connect a user's browsing session to a phone call made with a different device though. You could ask the user to input their ID in order to start the call, using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) to receive the input and tie that call to the user and whether they currently have a live session on the site. That might be an unnecessary barrier to people calling though, so you'd have to weigh up that option.